# GatsbyJs tutorial one links not working after build

Tags: gatsby

I am trying to learn GatsbyJs, and following the tutorials. Although everything seems to work on development, the links to the pages2 and counter are not working after build. It is very annoying, is there a quick fix to this?
I am using the git as supplied on the tutoril page.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied the public folder to a static site s3 bucket, granted the necessary permissions for public access and everything started to work fine.
Sorry to having bothered you people.